# Different object names of a constructor

Tags: java

So i need to give different names for objects created by this class.
Would be perfect if i could create different names with an array like this:

build name[i] = new build();

"build" is a constructor
ik this doesn't make sense, any ideas how to implement this?

Comment: Implement what exactly? Your question is not very clear, maybe you could exemplify with some code or what the purpose is. Are you simply talking about different variable names or creating a collection of objects?

Comment: What do you mean by the "name" of an object?   Objects don't naturally have names, unless you have provided a way for them to be named, such as passing in a name to be stored in the object, say via constructor arguments.  Are you talking about the name of the variable you use to refer to the object?  But that's simple: ```foo = new Thing(); bar = new Thing()``` so that seems unlikely to be what you want.  Please clarify.

Comment: Yes exactly i need different names for the variables of the object. Yes i know it's that simple, but i need to create a collection (as Joakim said) of it. That's why an array would be useful for the names of the variables.

Comment: Don't store variable names. It won't help, you can not easily access an instance dynamically by its variable name. That's not how people code. Instead, store your objects in a collection and access them from the collection. Instances are in no way tied to variable names pointing to them. Do not confuse variables with the instances they point to.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you create a hashmap which maps strings to your objecttype.

```
Map<String, Objectname> objects = new Hashmap<String, Objectname>();

String[] names = {/*names here*/};

for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    objects.put(names[i], new Objectname());
}
```

When you want to access the object:

```
Objectname object = objects.get(names[index]};
```